BlenderKit v3.12.3 not showing on add on list. no error message
I’m using blender v4.0 and downloaded blender kit v3.12.3. When I go to install from disk and choose my .zip file nothing happens. I receive no error message.

Long story short, that sounds correct, so either you’ve misunderstood / misdescribed a step or something’s broken.

Hello have you looked at https://www.blenderkit.com/docs/add-on-troubleshooting/ ?
